# How to create HTML dynamic to after create XML or JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, xml

I need to create a web page dynamic, where a layman User can enter information as if he were editing an XML or JSON, and after that need to convert this html in a json.

To convert html json already I found several examples using ajax for example, like this:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});
```

But I have no idea if it's possible to make an html where the elements can be ordered as a JSON.

I found an example to create dynamic forms with Bootstrap like this: http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/

The doubt is: 
Sorting these elements to convert into a JSON? 
How to know where will be an array or just a key-value set?

It is possible to create something?

Scenario: Today developers create a JSON to enter information into the system, we want commercial people can do this without knowing JSON with a friendly interface.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$.serializeArray()` already gives you a sorted array of the form fields with values, see https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ - generally: Array elements will keep their order, object properties don't have a fixed order. If you serialize your form into an array, you can be sure about the ordering, if you serialize it into an object the order of the properties is random.

Comment: What worries me is knowing what value belongs to which key, to form arrays for example.
{
  "key": {
    "key": [
      "value",
      "value",
      { "key": "value" }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: If your form has multiple inputs with the same name, the value can be an array. To check if it's an array or string, you can iterate the properties / values and check the type, e.g. with `typeof value === 'string'` or with `Array.isArray(value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
     createTextBox('formulario','campo1','valor1');
 });

function createTextBox(parent, name, value)
{
    var node = '<div class="node" id="node_'+name+'">'
                + '<input placeholder="" type="text" id="value_'+name+'" name="value_'+name+'"  value="'+value+'" />'
                + '<input placeholder="" type="text" id="value2_'+name+'" name="value2_'+name+'"  value="'+value+'" />'
                + '<input placeholder="" type="text" id="parent_'+name+'" name="parent_'+name+'" value="'+parent+'" />'
                + '<div id="nested_'+name+'" style="padding-left: 10%;" ><a href="#" onclick="addNested(this)" >ADD NESTED</a></div>'
                +'</div>';              

    $('#'+parent).append(node);
    //parse2Json();                
}

function addNested(object)
{
    var name = getNewName();
    createTextBox(object.parentElement.id, name , name);
}

function getRandomName() {
    var ret;

    if (!Date.now) {
        ret = function() { return new Date().getTime();
        }
    } else {
        ret = Date.now();
    }

    return ret;
}

function getNewName() {
    var ret = $("#count_campo").val();

    $("#count_campo").val(parseInt(ret)+1);

    return ret;
}

function parse2Json()
{
    //pegando todos os elementos node
    $('.node').each(function(index, obj) {

       alert("pai:"+ obj.parentElement.id);
       alert("id:"+ obj.id);

       alert("Campo 1: Id["+$("#"+obj.id).children(1).attr('name') +"] Value["+$("#"+obj.id).children(1).val()+"]");       
       alert("Campo 2: Id["+$("#"+obj.id).children(2).attr('name') +"] Value["+$("#"+obj.id).children(2).val()+"]");  //     IGUAL ->  //var c = obj.childNodes[2].text;

        //getting all elements inside div
        var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(obj.childNodes);

        array.forEach(function(objecto_filho) {
            alert("Dentro Foreach: "+ objecto_filho.id);
        });     

      //ou

    });

}

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="count_campo" name="count_campo" value="1" />

    <h1>Testes XML config</h1>
    <div id="formulario">

    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you need to create interface elements dynamically from XML or JSON file. One of possible way can looks like:

```
//Stored elements description for dynamic creation. Value if you need to store users data from elements
var dynamicElements = {
  'firstName' :{
    'type': 'input',
    'value': ''
  },
  'lastName': {
    'type': 'input',
    'value': ''
  }
}

for (elementId in dynamicElements) {
  var elementDescription = dynamicElements[elementId];
  var element = document.createElement(elementDescription.type);
  element.id = elementId;

  //do smth ... append it to form or any container
}
```

To convert from html to Json code you can add class for all dynamic inputs for your customers. Converting to JSON can looks like:

```
var inputsData = [];

jQuery(".oneOfMyAwesomeDynamicElements").each(function(index, element) {
  inputsData.push({
    'type': element.tagName,
    'value': element.value,
    'id': element.id
    //all element attribute you need
  });
})
```

Comment: No... I need the opposite of that ... I need a dynamic layout in HTML that looks like a JSON, where a layman can enter information as if that person were creating a json behind (or xml) 

Scenario: Today developers create a JSON to enter information into the system, we want commercial people can do this without knowing JSON with a friendly interface.